# What does "do the 45" mean?

Tags: lyrics

As a non native speaker I'm quite stumped trying to understand what "do the 45" means [in this song](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tm57vk4xgbb4sjfcsmtny4f63xe?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics&u=0#) by Ryan Shaw that has the same title.

A few searches didn't help at all, so I wonder if this is some kind of lesser known idiom or obscure reference that I don't get just because it's a cultural thing. I know that 45 could refer to a revolver, but the song doesn't sound like it has anything to do with firearms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the context, he seems to be referring to a **.45 caliber hand gun.**

It may be important to note that there have been many songs over the years that set a serious topic to upbeat music. One of the most famous examples is [Electric Avenue by Eddy Grant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtPk5IUbdH0).

---

## [The lyrics as I hear them:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqQz1MxRKX4)

> 45, yeah, do the 45. (x2)
>
> **Well, you heard about the shotgun, how bad it's gonna be.** I got news for you baby; just listen to me.
>
> You're twining and whining, like all the rest. **Well, I got my 45, and I'll create a big mess.**
>
> 45, yeah, do the 45. (x2)
>
> Well, here comes little sister; she's twisting up a storm. **She's doin' the 38** and she's waving her arms.
>
> Well come on, young girl, and dance with me. I've got my 45, and I'm as bad I can be.
>
> Now don't just stand there lookin' so dumb. **Act like Jesse James and have you some fun.**
>
> Everybody's dancing and moving all around. They've got their 45s and they're the best in town.
>
> 45, yeah, do the 45. (x2)
>
> Come on girl, do the 45, twist up a storm baby, do the 45. Whining and twining, do the 45.  Hey, hey hey.
>
> 45, do the 45. (repeats)

---

## Interpretation of bold lines:

**Well, you heard about the shotgun, how bad it's gonna be.** : A shotgun is another type of gun. Shootings are considered a bad thing.

**Well, I got my 45, and I'll create a big mess** : Again, shootings are bad. They create a "mess" in the literal sense that bodies and crime scenes will need to be cleaned-up, as well as political and social fallout (riots, protests, etc.)

**She's doin' the 38** : A "38" commonly refers to a .38 caliber hand gun. This is what sealed the hand gun analogy for me. A 45 can also be a record, but there are no 38 records.

**Act like Jesse James and have you some fun.** : [Jesse James](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_James) was an infamous outlaw in "Old West" of the United States. He was known to be violent and to have murdered many people.

---

**Other uses of "45" outside of a firearm:**

"45" record: The most common form of the vinyl single is the 45 or 7-inch. The names are derived from its play speed, 45 rpm, and the standard diameter, 7 inches (18 cm).

"Colt 45": Refers to cheap malt liquor, and is made even more famous in the song [Crazy Rap by Afroman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfpUCBDQrDI) (caution explicit lyrics).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised, though, if "45" has some other slang connotation, perhaps sexual, and there's a double entendre of sorts.

Comment: @HotLicks Rule 34 engaged

Comment: Well, actually there is a definite double entendre, as we have the sentence "Well, I got my body poppin' out for you to witness", clearly referring to the male sexual organ.  And of course that's often regarded as a gun.  But my guess is that "45" and perhaps "38" have slang connotations unrelated to firearms, and those figure into the ultimate meaning of the lyrics.

Answer (score 2):

A "45" refers to the [Colt 45 revolver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colt_Single_Action_Army), or a later gun derived from it.

So to "do the 45" refers to *using s*uch a gun.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I wasn't aware that "doing" could be used in that particular way.

Comment: why does it have to be a Colt Revolver? there are many .45 caliber guns...

Comment: @Skooba: That's true today. But it's "original" context was the "Colt 45." That's why I used it as a reference.

Comment: @S.m.: It's American slang. I believe that it corresponds most closely to the Italian facciare,

Comment: @TomAu sure, "do" means "fare", but it still sounded new to me in this context, in the same way it did when I learned that "to do" someone meant to have intercourse with them. Thanks again, I learned something new!

Comment: @s.m. Songs often play with the meaning of words. "To do the X" is a common expression where X is the name of a dance; that's almost certainly what's being referenced here. "The 45" is being used metaphorically, as if it were the name of a dance. The phrase "do the 45" doesn't mean anything outside of the metaphor.

Comment: @trentcl: You don't usually "create a big mess" by doing a dance. Much more often with a gun.

Comment: @TomAu It's the dance that is metaphorical, or that's how I read it. Are you saying that "doing the 45" has a meaningful interpretation in the absence of context?

Comment: @trentcl: IMHO, yes.

Comment: @TomAu Really? You don't think "do the 45" is a reference to other songs with similar lyrics, like "do the loco-motion" or "the hokey-pokey"? I'm really not sure how you could interpret that any other way. To be clear, I'm not saying the 45 is a dance; I'm saying the phrase being used intentionally evokes the idea of someone dancing. I don't know how it could be understood any other way.

Comment: @trentcl: Yes, it does evoke dancing, but to me (growing up in the 1960s), it also evokes "cowboys and Indians" and the "lone ranger."

Comment: @TomAu Yes. It has multiple layers of meaning and both are intended.

Comment: @s.m "Do / doing drugs" (or a more specific term like "doing weed") is a common phrase instead of "use / using drugs". or "take / taking drugs." "Do the 45" is analogous to that. It's hardly "slang" - Former UK prime minister Tony Blair was once made some remarks about politics and religion in a TV interview, and one if his advisors later said "we don't do God". http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk_politics/4773852.stm

Comment: @alephzero: Such terms were (American) "slang" when I was growing up in the 1960s. I guess they've become "mainstream" since then.